# Can't install SQL Server 2014 on WIndows 7 - HRESULT 0x8007370B

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I keep receiving the following errors:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Setup
------------------------------

The following error has occurred:

An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8007370B. 

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=0xDF039760%25401201%25401

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

[image: First error window that comes up]

and then the following error:

[image]

Googling on HRESULT 8007370B doesn't yield much results except for people who are looking for "System Update Readiness".

I've run multiple "registry fix" programs; 
`sfc /SCANNOW` gives me the error "windows resource protection could not perform the requested operation".

**Anyone have any ideas?**

Here is the log file:

```
    Overall summary:
      Final result:                  Failed: see details below
      Exit code (Decimal):           -2068052081
      Start time:                    2014-12-08 14:07:24
      End time:                      2014-12-08 14:16:06
      Requested action:              Install

    Setup completed with required actions for features.
    Troubleshooting information for those features:
      Next step for Adv_SSMS:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Next step for Conn:            Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Next step for SDK:             Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Next step for BC:              Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Next step for SSMS:            Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Next step for RS:              Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Next step for FullText:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Next step for Replication:     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Next step for Browser:         Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Next step for BOL:             Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Next step for ComponentUpdate: Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.


    Machine Properties:
      Machine name:                  DHW018661
      Machine processor count:       4
      OS version:                    Windows 7
      OS service pack:               Service Pack 1
      OS region:                     United States
      OS language:                   English (United States)
      OS architecture:               x64
      Process architecture:          64 Bit
      OS clustered:                  No

    Product features discovered:
      Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

    Package properties:
      Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2014 
      ProductName:                   SQL Server 2014
      Type:                          RTM
      Version:                       12
      SPLevel:                       0
      Installation location:         E:\x64\setup\
      Installation edition:          Express

    Product Update Status:
      None discovered.

    User Input Settings:
      ACTION:                        Install
      ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      true
      AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
      AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
      AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled
      ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
      ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
      ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
      ASDATADIR:                     Data
      ASLOGDIR:                      Log
      ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
      ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
      ASSVCACCOUNT:                  
      ASSVCPASSWORD:                 
      ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
      ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            
      ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
      BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
      CLTCTLRNAME:                   
      CLTRESULTDIR:                  
      CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
      CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 
      CLTSVCPASSWORD:                
      CLTWORKINGDIR:                 
      COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
      COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
      COMMFABRICPORT:                0
      CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141208_140724\ConfigurationFile.ini
      CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
      CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                
      CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               
      CTLRUSERS:                     
      ENABLERANU:                    true
      ENU:                           true
      ERRORREPORTING:                false
      FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, REPLICATION, FULLTEXT, RS, CONN, BC, SDK, BOL, SSMS, ADV_SSMS, LOCALDB
      FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
      FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           
      FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher$SQLEXPRESS
      FTSVCPASSWORD:                 
      HELP:                          false
      IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
      INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
      INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
      INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
      INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             
      INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
      INSTANCEID:                    SQLEXPRESS
      INSTANCENAME:                  SQLEXPRESS
      ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
      ISSVCPASSWORD:                 
      ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
      MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
      MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            
      MATRIXNAME:                    
      NPENABLED:                     0
      PID:                           *****
      QUIET:                         false
      QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
      ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
      RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
      RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
      RSSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\ReportServer$SQLEXPRESS
      RSSVCPASSWORD:                 
      RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
      SAPWD:                         
      SECURITYMODE:                  
      SQLBACKUPDIR:                  
      SQLCOLLATION:                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
      SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
      SQLSVCPASSWORD:                
      SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
      SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           HEAD_OFFICE\clozid1
      SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  
      SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               
      SQLUSERDBDIR:                  
      SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               
      SQMREPORTING:                  false
      TCPENABLED:                    0
      UIMODE:                        Normal
      UpdateEnabled:                 true
      UpdateSource:                  MU
      USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
      X86:                           false

      Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141208_140724\ConfigurationFile.ini

    Detailed results:
      Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
      Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
      Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
      Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Setup Support Files
      Component error code:          1935
      Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141208_140724\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1.log
      Error description:             An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8007370B.
      Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40CreateShortcuts%401935%3a0x8007370B

      Feature:                       Client Tools Connectivity
      Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
      Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
      Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Setup Support Files
      Component error code:          1935
      Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141208_140724\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1.log
      Error description:             An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8007370B.
      Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40CreateShortcuts%401935%3a0x8007370B

      Feature:                       Client Tools SDK
      Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
      Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
      Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Setup Support Files
      Component error code:          1935
      Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141208_140724\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1.log
      Error description:             An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8007370B.
      Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40CreateShortcuts%401935%3a0x8007370B

      Feature:                       Client Tools Backwards Compatibility
      Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
      Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
      Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Setup Support Files
      Component error code:          1935
      Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141208_140724\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1.log
      Error description:             An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8007370B.
      Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40CreateShortcuts%401935%3a0x8007370B

      Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
      Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
      Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
      Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Setup Support Files
      Component error code:          1935
      Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141208_140724\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1.log
      Error description:             An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8007370B.
      Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40CreateShortcuts%401935%3a0x8007370B

      Feature:                       Reporting Services - Native
      Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
      Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
      Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Setup Support Files
      Component error code:          1935
      Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141208_140724\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1.log
      Error description:             An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8007370B.
      Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40CreateShortcuts%401935%3a0x8007370B

      Feature:                       Database Engine Services
      Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
      Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
      Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Setup Support Files
      Component error code:          1935
      Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141208_140724\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1.log
      Error description:             An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8007370B.
      Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40CreateShortcuts%401935%3a0x8007370B

      Feature:                       Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
      Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
      Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
      Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Setup Support Files
      Component error code:          1935
      Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141208_140724\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1.log
      Error description:             An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8007370B.
      Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40CreateShortcuts%401935%3a0x8007370B

      Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
      Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
      Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
      Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Setup Support Files
      Component error code:          1935
      Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141208_140724\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1.log
      Error description:             An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8007370B.
      Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40CreateShortcuts%401935%3a0x8007370B

      Feature:                       SQL Browser
      Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
      Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
      Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Setup Support Files
      Component error code:          1935
      Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141208_140724\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1.log
      Error description:             An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8007370B.
      Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40CreateShortcuts%401935%3a0x8007370B

      Feature:                       Documentation Components
      Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
      Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
      Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Setup Support Files
      Component error code:          1935
      Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141208_140724\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1.log
      Error description:             An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8007370B.
      Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40CreateShortcuts%401935%3a0x8007370B

      Feature:                       LocalDB
      Status:                        Passed

      Feature:                       Setup Support Files
      Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
      Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
      Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Setup Support Files
      Component error code:          1935
      Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141208_140724\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1.log
      Error description:             An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8007370B.
      Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40CreateShortcuts%401935%3a0x8007370B

    Rules with failures:

    Global rules:

    Scenario specific rules:

    Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141208_140724\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

EDIT: I installed 2008 R2 on the same machine with no problems. I then tried both a full install of 2014 and an "upgrade" install, both resulting in the same error above.

Comment: Don't just down-vote. Give a reason why.

Comment: For me, even with the error, it has installed everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue and got SQL Server 2014 installed.

Since the C++ updates wouldn’t get installed (or whatever the issue was with that `VC80.ATL` message, I did a backtrack and looked for programs that would fix Windows Update issues.

I found the Windows Readiness Tool:
http://mintywhite.com/windows-7/7maintenance/trouble-installing-windows-updates-system-update-readiness-tool-windows/

I ran it. It took about 20 minutes to run.

I then ran the SQL Server 2014 installation and everything went through fine.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue a few minutes ago.  I had a pending Windows Update reboot while I was trying to install it.  After I rebooted and let the update finish the SQL Server install went through fine.

This can also happen because of some corrupted files.  See this MSDN post (it's for an older SQL Server version but it's the same issue with the same file, you'll have to repair a C++ redistributable install).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2010/04/23/sql-server-2005-setup-fails-on-windows-2008-due-to-corrupt-vc-component.aspx

(Steps from the blog post for posterity, they may need to be altered slightly depending on if you need the x86 or x64 redistributable)

1. Go to START, RUN, type in INSTALLER and press Enter (to pull up the installer directory).
2. Arrange the window in Details view.
3. Right click the header and click add columns.
4. Check the checkbox for Comments column.
5. In the comments column, look for Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 redistributable RTL.
6. Right click the msi and click Repair the VC++ 2005 redistributable.
7. The repair process will look for vcredist.msi in the temp folder and most probably it will not find it there and prompt to provide location for the same file.
8. Downloaded the VC++ 2005 redistributable from: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=32bc1bee-a3f9-4c13-9c99-220b62a191ee&displaylang=en
9. We need to extracted the exe using the following commands at command prompt: 
   a.       C:>vcredist_x86.exe /C
   b.       C:>"VCREDI~1.EXE" /C
10. After running the above steps, we get the vcredist.msi extracted.
11. Provide the location for vcredist.msi for prompt in Step7.

Once the repair is complete, start the SQL Setup and this should help installing SQL Server successfully

Comment: This solution doesn't work. Every time I try and point to the files at step 11, it says, "the file c:\temp\...\vcredist.msi is not a valid installation for the product Mirosoft Visual C++ 2005...' Try to find the installation package 'vcredist.msi' in a folder from what you can install Microsoft Visual C++ 2005.... "

Comment: I had also a pending update, so after restarting I was able to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I got the same errorcode with an Installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 in Windows 2008 SP2. 
Solution was to download and install the Visual C Redistributable Package. (VC80) and afterwards retry the installation again. I guess that it's also the case for Windows 7. 
In this Blog Post I summarized it also with the Downloadlink from Microsoft.

https://cms4j.wordpress.com/2016/12/12/sql-server-2008-r2-installation-failed-2068052081-1212-1935/

Answer (score 0):

6 years later, I still encountered this same problem, same error message in Windows 10.
What fixed it for me is to go to DCOMCNFG and set the Authentication Level to "Connect".
Prior to that, it was set to "None". 
[image]

Answer (score -2):

I downloaded the fresh copy from microsoft website for the installation and installation succeeded perfectly. As others are saying to check the prerequisites for the installation. It is by default tested by the setup of sql. I only proceed after completing the prerequisite. but there were errors. but with clean copy of iso downloaded from microsoft it resolved.

Comment: This is not a useful response, as you don't directly answer the question regarding the errors reported