# Unable to install SqlServer 2014 setup

Tags: sql-server-2014-express

I'm trying to install Sql Server 2014 Express(SQLEXPR_x64_ENU) in my Windows 8.1 (64- Bit Operating system , x64- Based processor);But I'm unable to install the software and getting error as followed:"Error 1935.An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL";
Can anyone suggest me what could be the resolution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer you are looking for is in the below link. Check that out.

[Can't install SQL Server 2014 on WIndows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352413/cant-install-sql-server-2014-on-windows-7-hresult-0x8007370b)

Comment: I'm getting the same error as mentioned in the post, however, remedy for my Windows 8.1 is not available there. Can you help me with it.